# Modify Excel's defined Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml

I have to rename Excel sheets using **OpenXml** but when this is done the references to these sheets will no longer work. I've been trying to alter the `innerXml` of `DefinedName` using **OpenXml** but it won't set the value. 
Here's what I have so far:

```
private void Renamesheet(string sheetName, string newSheetName, string filePath)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

        Sheet sheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

        sheet.Name = newSheetName;
        var names = wbPart.Workbook.DefinedNames.Where(x => x.InnerText.ToString().Contains("'" + sheetName + "'"));
        var i = 0;
        while (i < names.Count())
        {
            names.ElementAt(i).InnerXml = names.ElementAt(i).InnerXml.Replace(sheetName, newSheetName);   
            i++;
        }
        wbPart.Workbook.Save();
    }

}
```

I'm using the while loop instead of a foreach because I read that might fix this issue but it did not. Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you save the changes before exiting the `using` statement. I'm not sure that the using statement will save your changes to disk automatically when being disposed. Try saving it explicitly.

Comment: Oops I didn't add that to the snippet. It is in my code though. I'll edit it now.

Comment: What are the sheet names?  You are searching for them with single quotes around them.  If there are no spaces in the name, then it is possible that they are in the formulas without the quotes.  I think your search will work as well without the single quotes if you want to give that a run.

Comment: I checked, they are in the formulas with single quotes. I debugged it and am sure I am getting the names, I just can't change the value of DefinedName. Basically the part inside the while loop is just not doing anything.

Comment: So overall aim is to edit the SheetName to something else, AM I correct ?

Comment: Yea basically Im renaming a bunch of template sheets and then need to rename the references that were using the old sheet name

Answer (score 1):

```
   WorkbookPart w=  document.WorkbookPart;
                Sheet sheet = w.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "abc").FirstOrDefault();
                sheet.Name = "dreamers";  (1)
                w.Workbook.Save();
```

Above three lines changes the sheetname, as soon as line (1)  will be executed 
 var names = wbPart.Workbook.DefinedNames.Where(x => x.InnerText.ToString().Contains("'" + sheetName + "'"));

line will throw a null reference exception as the name will be changed.

And in any case the excel dont have same DefinedNames for two sheets so where will return one sheet, hence while loop not needed. User FirstOrDefault() instead of while.